# How ca I set a variable in java backend when maven build is executed?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I implemented a Developer Feature which can only be accessed when a variable in the java backend is set to true. I already implemented a color change in the frontend for the user, so he does not forget to disable the variable.

But is there a way that I can set a variable when `mvn clean install` is executed?

Answer (score 1):

I would propose that you use an environment variable for this. You can use

```
System.getEnv()
```

to get the variable during runtime and use

```
mvn -DmyVariable=someValue install
```

to set it using Maven. Another option is to use a properties file like this https://mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: The environment variable should maybe to it, gonna try it.
Thank you very much so far!

Comment: Happy to help. Did it work? If you then I would be grateful if you set this as an accepted answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to move to another project and therefore had no time to try it out. But I should have some time for the project in the following months. I will let you know. But thanks for the help so far!